# What are some possible reasons that you would get an undefined method 'TheModelName_path' error using a form_for in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I can't figure out why I have this error from my knowledge everything is set up as it should to work.

**this is the error i get:** 
NoMethodError at /short/new
undefined method `shorts_path' for #<#:0x007fbc441426e0>

1. my model is short not shortS
2. when I run rake routes there is no `shorts_path` so I'm not sure where this helper is coming from. I don't understand why the `form_for` is giving me this error when `@short` is defined in the `def new` section of my controller.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Thank you in advance

**This is what my controller looks like**

```
class ShortController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @short = Short.find(params[:id].to_i(36))

        respond_to do |format|
            #redirect directly to the url stored as long in the database
            format.html { redirect_to @short.long}
        end
    end

    def new
        @short = Short.new

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # new.html.erb
        end
    end

    def create
        @short = Short.new(params[:short])

        respond_to do |format|
            if @short.save

                format.html { render action: "show" }

            else

                format.html { render action: "new" }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**routes**

```
Trainingproject::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'short#welcome'
  resources :short, :only => [:new, :create, :show]
end
```

**form partial which is rendered in the view for new**

```
<%= form_for(@short) do |f| %>
    <% if @short.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@short.errors.count,"error") %> prohibited this url from being saved:</h2>
            <ul>
                <% @short.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li><%= msg %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

        <div class="form-field">
            <%= f.label "Enter your URL" %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :long %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `form_for(@short)`, where `@short` is a new `Short` record, will attempt to use the path helper called `shorts_path` to route to where the form needs to go. You're missing this route definition in your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
 resources :shorts
```

Please read the [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and [Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guides, which should explain the things that you're missing.